# Shell Script and C Program in ROS

Tags: shell, ubuntu, ros-electric, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have been using ROS now for quiet a good time and have been able to achieve several applications. However, recently i came up with a new requirement of having the capability to make ROS run shell scripts and C programs. Although I have some idea on this using some crude Linux methods, I would like to know if there is any formal method of being able to do this?

I have a custom code for a specific application written in C and the operations of the code is invoked using shell commands. I would like to incorporate this into ROS environment to complete my task.

Any relevant information could help me on this.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with ROS-fuerte and another system with Ubuntu 11.10 and ROS-electric.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39502/shell-script-and-c-program-in-ros/) by [SivamPillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2018/sivampillai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 612 on 2012-07-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PerkinsJames](https://answers.ros.org/users/2621/perkinsjames/) on 2012-07-23**:
If you mean using something like system(), I don't see why you consider that crude.

**Comment by [SivamPillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2018/sivampillai/) on 2012-07-23**:
I said so just because I thought it would be more a linux way than a ROS way. But if there was no other option I would go with the system() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Depending on what you intent to do I see two possibilities:

1. Call your C program/shell script from ROS, either by system() within a node or you can also rosrun/roslaunch non-ROS executables.
2. Integrate your code with ROS by building it as a ROS package, writing a ROS interface or making it available as a library.

Some hints might be here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/UsingThirdPartyLibraries

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SivamPillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2018/sivampillai/) on 2012-07-23**:
could you please expand more on (2). My code is itself a collection of c-files and headers whcih requires command line arguments as the input filename, does processing and generates a few output files... These output files would be required by me in further stages of my ROS nodes.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-07-24**:
2 means, you basically build your code with ROS. It doesn't even require to integrate ROS with the code. Usually I'd start with roscreate-pkg of an empty roscpp package, put my sources in and enter them in CMakeLists.txt. Normally this should then compile already as a package.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-07-24**:
You could now also setup launch files that provide the correct command line arguments, possibly relative to packages, etc.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-07-24**:
If you need to regularly call this, a system() call is also OK. I'd still recommend building it as a package though as then you can use rosrun in the system call and are independent of hardcoded paths.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-07-24**:
If you really want the ROS way, scrap the input/output files and send around messages instead.

**Comment by [SivamPillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2018/sivampillai/) on 2012-07-24**:
That sounds pretty interesting and hopeful. I would try to do such things and would update if i get stuck up somewhere :) Sending around messages instead of files would mean making a lot of modification in my source files and I would want to avoid that for now. Thanks.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-07-24**:
Usually one only writes a ros interface wrapper file that uses the library API. If that is possible depends on your code.

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2014-12-31**:
DOMHEGE, How to do 1st method plz give me one example. Means how to call C on ROS